# Sympy convolution of uniform probability distributions gets intractable too quickly

Tags: sympy, probability, probability-density

I have a several independent uniform probability distributions, each with a different width (i.e. they are Uniform(0,width) where width is different for each of the distribution).
I would like to obtain a probability distribution of their sum. If the width parameter would be the same for all of them, the distribution of the sum would be a [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). However, as the width differs for each of the unfirom distribution, I am not aware of any known solution.

Therefore, I tried to compute the distribution symbolically using SymPy, by iteratively computing the [convolution integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions).
This work ok for a sum of 2-3 uniform distributions, but the integration gets stuck after the third iteration.

```
from time import time
from sympy.functions.elementary.piecewise import Piecewise
from sympy import Symbol, oo, simplify, integrate

t = Symbol('t')
widths = [7, 5, 14, 32, 3]
uniforms = [Piecewise((1 / width, (t <= width) & (t >= 0)), (0, True)) for width in widths]


def convolution(f, g, t, lower_limit=-oo, upper_limit=oo):
    tau = Symbol('tau')
    return integrate(f.subs(t, tau) * g.subs(t, t - tau),
                     (tau, lower_limit, upper_limit))


pdf = uniforms[0]
for uniform in uniforms[1:]:
    time_start = time()
    pdf = simplify(convolution(pdf, uniform, t))
    print(f"Convolution took {round(time() - time_start, 3)}s.")
```

First iteration took 0.194s, second 0.69s and then the subsequent iterations didn't finished (in reasonable time). While I expected the subsequent computation to be more and more complex, I am a bit suprised that it become untractable at just the third convolution. (Compare to the Irwin-Hall distribution mentioned above, which looks kinda simple even for a sum of 5 distributions). I suspect that maybe I am using Sympy in a wrong way / there is some issue with my code?

Comment: I don't know about Sympy, but I worked on this problem in Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io), and I was able to get something working for large numbers of terms. It's kind of disorganized, but if you want to take a look, see the folder `boxcar_convolution` at: https://github.com/maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages/tree/master/robert-dodier I can't take the time to sort it out now, but if you are interested I can figure it out this weekend. In any event, maybe that stuff can be an inspiration as to how to implement it in Sympy.

Comment: Aside from exact solutions, a very close approximation is to discretize the distributions in question, and compute the discrete convolution. The `conv` function in Octave or Matlab computes convolutions via FFT. The approximation is closer the smaller you make the intervals for the discretization; given that FFT is very fast, you can make the intervals very small, obtaining a very close approximation.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier; we ended up just sampling from the distribution of sums (which can be done easily by just sampling from the individual uniform distributions and summing the results) and using the samples to get histogram / quantiles we were interested in. Also will check out the discrete convolution.

Comment: Jakub, I'm glad to hear you got it working. One advantage of the discrete convolution is that it is much more efficient than sampling -- you get a more accurate result for much less computation.

Comment: @RobertDodier It could be done using convolution theorem, please check my answer. I don't know Maxima, but may be it could be redone in Maxima (or SymPy)

Answer (score 1):

You could get analytical answer using [Convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). Make Fourier transform of the original PDF, multiply them and then make inverse Fourier transform to get the result.

Mathematica v12 could do that fast

```
U01[x_, a_] := (Sign[x] + Sign[a-x])/2/a
Plot[U01[x,2],{x,-1.6,3.6}, PlotStyle->Thick]

CFU01[w_, a_]:=Evaluate[FourierTransform[U01[x,a],x, w]]

PDF1 = InverseFourierTransform[CFU01[w, a1], w, x]
PDF2 = InverseFourierTransform[CFU01[w, a1] CFU01[w, a2], w, x]
PDF3 = InverseFourierTransform[CFU01[w, a1] CFU01[w, a2] CFU01[w, a3], w, x]
```

last one being

```
(1/(4 a1 a2 a3))
HeavisideTheta[a1] HeavisideTheta[a2] HeavisideTheta[a3] ((a1 + a2 + a3 - x)^2 Sign[
 a1 + a2 + a3 - x] - (a1 + a2 - x)^2 Sign[
 a1 + a2 - x] - (a1 + a3 - x)^2 Sign[
 a1 + a3 - x] + (a1 - x)^2 (-Sign[x - a1]) - (a2 + a3 - x)^2 Sign[
 a2 + a3 - x] - (a2 - x)^2 Sign[x - a2] - (a3 - x)^2 Sign[
 x - a3] + x^2 Sign[x])
```